# How to set data to layout inflated by a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-inflate

I have a FragmentActivity which sets a main layout with 3 tabs. Each tab has it's own fragment which inflates is own layout into main layout.

For example, one of the three Fragments:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
  }
}
```

When I add all the fragments and connect them with tabs everything works. When I click on tab1, layout of the Fragment1 shows, when I click on Tab2, layout of the Fragment2 shows.

The problem is that when I want to change something in that inflated layout (for example execute setText to textView in fragment1 layout), I receive a NullPointerException in that line and application stops.

This doesn't work:

```
 TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragmentOneText1);
 test.setText("Test text!");
```

How to set data to inflated layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inflate your fragment specific layout first by using `LayoutInflater` and map the control in your Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        TextView text = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentOneText1);
        mTextNoResult=(TextView)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.text_noresult);
        return fragmentView;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a little bit? I don't understand this with LayoutInflater. Where I need to use it?

Comment: Just replace your `onCreateView()` with my code,LayoutInflater will inflate particular layout(fragment1) to your Fragment.

Comment: It works! I would just like to ask you one more question. How to transfer data now from FragmentActivity to Fragment? Results which are generated in FragmentActivity needs to be displayed in that inflated layout. Thank you!

Comment: In FragmentActivity use `fragObj.setArguments(mBundle)`, and in Fragment class `mBundle= getArguments` thats it.